# Javascript - Interacting with the OS

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

I'm implementing a specialized cloud storage solution. As part of the deal, I supply a client app similar to "Google Drive"/Dropbox. This app is quite good because it not only keeps everything synced but also, when uploading a file, it can significantly increase upload speed.

My problem here is that a lot of times, the users HAVE the client app installed, but forget to use it, and upload new files via browser. So I was wondering if there's a way to make the browser report back to my app if my client app is installed.

I know that I can't run a app via javascript, but I was thinking can I ask if "there is someone who knows how to read the extension .XPTO" using javascript? because I can bind the extension to my app, and if there's no responder, I could proceed with regular browser upload...